# Composer - Is it possible to install packages in "require-dev" globally with one command?

Tags: php, jenkins, continuous-integration, composer-php, continuous-delivery

quick question, and please let me know if anything about my idea is silly in general / if there is a better approach to this:

For the purpose of creating a Continuous Delivery pipeline, I would like to declare some packages needed for various types of tests in Composer with "require-dev". However, I am wondering if it was possible to run the install command in a way that it would install all packages listed under "require-dev" globally with one command?

It would be nice, since it would allow me to keep the test environments up-to-date with ease and allow for global access of all PHP Testing solutions I need. I know it is not much work and I would already be done with it if I just went through all of them manually, but I was curious to know if there was a nice way of doing this, since I think downloading and everything by hand, giving it execution rights and then moving it to the bin/ directory for global access is kind of a tedious solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the composer's help using the **global** keyword with the composer allow running commands in the global composer dir ($COMPOSER_HOME).

This means when you run `composer global require phpunit/phpunit`, composer will update its global directory instead of the directory you are in at that moment.

so in my case, **$COMPOSER_HOME** is in my home directory **/Home/.composer**, running the above command will;

1. update the /Home/.composer/composer.json file.
2. Download the latest phpunit package to the /Home/.composer/vender
3. Add a symlink to the phpunit executable file into the /Home/.composer/vendor/bin directory

so at this point if i have the **bin** folder included in my paths i would be able to run phpunit within my system regardless of which directory i'm running the command in.

Now if you prefer the dependency to be installed as part of the development requirement all you need to do is to add **--dev** parameter to the install (or update) command as well e.g. `composer global require phpunit/phpunit --dev`

Comment: to install more than one package with a single command, just list them with a space between them :) **e.g.** `composer global require phpunit/phpunit:4.7.0 league/csv:7.0.0 --dev`

Answer (score 0):

What is that global install supposed to do?

The usual thing to do would be to install Phpunit. Now it wouldn't help you if you have two projects, one using the old version 3.7, and the newer using 4.6, to install any version globally.

Don't install dependencies globally that are used by a certain package explicitly.

However, tools that are not required, or are not stated to be required in a specific version, like PHP Codesniffer, can easily be installed centrally with

```
composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer
```

Then put the resulting path of ~/.composer/vendor/bin into the PATH environment variable. Note that ~ does not resolve there, you have to do that yourself.